# NSString drawInRect vs. Core Text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-text

I've read in the documentation that the `NSString` category method `drawInRect` is good for small amounts of text, but is too much overhead for large amounts. The alternative in my case would be to use Core Text `CTFrameDraw`.

My question is, what is the "cut-off" point between using `drawInRect` vs Core Text? Is Core Text always faster than `drawInRect`? If the extra programming is not the issue, should I always just use Core Text instead of `drawInRect`, even for small strings?

Mostly I'll be drawing paragraphs, but sometimes they can be short lines too.

Comment: The cut off is when, during testing and profiling, you notice that your app is responding too slowly and when you profile you notice that most of that unacceptable time is being spent inside `drawInRect:`.

Comment: Eh I'm sure there's a real answer to this..

Comment: That's the real answer. Somebody may be able to give some non-specific advice that they "felt" worked well in their situation, but since how you're drawing the string, what characters are in it, what font you use, etc. all make a huge difference, you need to test it for your case.

Comment: @Jason : Alas, that may be bad answer for mobile devices.  Not architecting/planning an app for *expected* hot spots can end up wasting the user's battery life.

Comment: @hotpaw2 That should be part of your testing and profiling. If something you're doing is draining battery, you should deal with it. The user asks questions that don't have yes-or-no answers. The answer is to prototype for your specific needs, profile, test and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it comes to use core text when I have some specific requirements from the graphic designer. For instance label that need to mix colors, type, font size etc. drawRect is method that draws something in a view layer, is just a wrapper around CG functions, core text is full framework to deal on how to draw text: change fonts, spaces, interlines.
I mean is not fair as a comparison, a better question could be when it comes to use core text instead of common UI text porpoise obejects and the answer is based on your app design-UI related requirements. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would write some test code to benchmark the two methods under consideration using your expected statistical distribution of string content.  Maybe a timing a few tens of millions of string renders using each.  Run the benchmarks on an actual iOS device, as relative performance may be different using the ARM targeted frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if using a UIWebView would get all the performance that's possible. The iOS (and every OS) has a constantly loaded webkit ready to go. Its pretty well optimized too. It would also get work offloaded.

Interesting to compare.